# Auto send news from followed sites to users via email

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, newsfeed, following

We want to send a news digest to users automatically. The mail should contain new/unread news posts from sites the user is following. Ideally this would happen on a fixed day in the week.

I found the auto-news digest feature, but [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-sending-news-post-digests-b930b579-0de5-4c67-86f0-de64b87c45e3) says, it only sends news that are posted by someone in the direct management chain of the user or someone they are closely working with.

Is it possible to send a news digest for the followed sites instead? If this isn't a feature, can it be created as a logic app, azure function, etc.? Or are there third party products?

So far my only idea is, to create a program that loops through all users, and for each user querys Graph API for their followed sites, gets news from this site via Search API, creates and sends an email and then continues with the next user.

Answer (score 0):

We could use Power Automate for SharePoint News Notifications automatically, however, this will work for all news post in one site, not for user followed sites.

[image]

For your requirement, currently there is no OOB way to do it.

More information for your reference:

https://sharepoint-tricks.com/get-notified-by-email-when-a-news-post-is-created-on-a-sharepoint-site/

https://collab365.com/using-flow-sharepoint-news-notifications/#

Comment: But that flow would send the email right away, no digest, right?

Comment: You could custom the digest it in email body, add related properties about the news post as shown above.